# Is there now a canonical ‘how to install packages’ question?

Tags: discussion

A common user question is ‘how do I install a package on platform X?’  There are a couple of hints of this on here, such as [a simple ‘adjust TEXINPUTS’ question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299796/latex-install-packages-in-home) and an [`apt-get install` question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142155/install-packages-in-ubuntu), and there's a [‘should we consolidate “how to install” questions’ meta-question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2670/should-how-to-install-package-x-on-ubuntu-questions-be-consolidated).  But I can't find a high-rep general answer, and the meta-question, though it has a good answer drafted, doesn't seem to have made it to the main site in a few years.
Have I just failed to find such a question?

I thought there'd be masses of duplicates of this question, but on reflection I can see why (*pace* my first sentence) this might not be as common as I'd have guessed: most people probably install pretty complete LaTeX installations rather than a bare-bones+tlmgr installation; and very few people will install packages from author tarballs.

My particular motivation is that I pointed to a beta version of a package in an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/311096/96), whereupon the questioner (reasonably enough) asked ‘fine, but how do I install that?’ I almost pointed towards Robin's venerable [UK TeX FAQ answer](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-inst-wlcf.html), but thought I could surely do better.

Comment: there are many questions already about vanilla and official installations with screenshots though I can't search on the phone right now

Comment: I think the best place for such a list of questions is in the [Installing answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/often-referenced-questions/2426#2426) of the [Often referenced questions post](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/often-referenced-questions). There are already 9 questions listed there.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Thanks – that's a good location. I thought I'd done a reasonably diligent search of the tex.se site, but it came up with little that was useful.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot (and if you were inclined to make that into a brief answer, I'd happily accept it)

Comment: @NormanGray Okay. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the meta site the [Often referenced questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/often-referenced-questions) post is the best place for lists of useful questions. This includes the [Installing](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2426) section, which lists the canonical "How to install" questions.